# Which Microsoft server version use for development - 2008 r2 or 2012?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, hosting

1. I am going to develop web app but so far I don't know which Windows server version to use - 2008 r2 or 2012 ? Currently I have 2012 installed but I saw that most hosting providers support 2008 so I am planning to go for 2008 . What do you think ? Any tips and opinions would be appreciated
2. I also interested if there can be issues in choosing ASP.NET MVC framework version. I plan to use ASP.NET MVC 4 but will it be supported by most hosting providers ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the new development, then you need to considered into account that Microsoft support for `Windows Server 2008` [ends up](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/default.aspx?LN=en-us&x=7&y=15&p1=12925) at the beginning of 2015...

As for hosting providers how about [Windows Azure for .NET](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/get-started/) (they already offers `ASP.NET MVC 5` hosting) and [Amazon for .Net](http://aws.amazon.com/net/)?

Do not worry about "most hosting providers" - use the latest technologies and have a fun!

Comment: I am worried that windows azure or amazon might have much bigger pricings than regular hosts. I would like to get smth that provides ~2gb of database for ~9$ / month

Comment: this must be cheaper :) http://discountasp.net/sp_mvc-hosting.aspx

Comment: you could also check for shared .NET hosting at http://www.howtoasp.net/asp-net-hosting/